# How to define the scalar multiplication to make $M/IM$ an $R/I$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules

Let $M$ be a $R$-module and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. How to define the scalar multiplication to make $M/IM$ a module over $R/I$? Here are my attempts.
Let $x+IM\in M/IM$ and $y+I\in R/I$, where $x\in M$ and $y\in R$. I define scalar multiplication by $(y+I)+(x+IM) = (x+y)+(I+IM)$ or $(y+I)(x+IM)=xy+yIM+xI+I\cdot IM$. And I failed at last.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, there's nothing special about $\frak m$ being a maximal ideal for this question. In general, try showing that given any ideal $I \subset R$, the module $M/IM$ is an $R/I$-module.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani: So this is my question, how to show $M/IM$ is an $R/I$-module?

Comment: If you show what you have tried and where it failed, may be we could help you fix your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m\in M$ and $r\in R$, we define the multiplication of $\overline m\in M/IM$ and $\overline r\in R/I$ as $\overline r\cdot\overline m:=\overline{rm}\in M/IM$. I will show well-definedness, since all other properties are fairly easy to show.

Let $m'\in M$ and $r'\in R$ be such that $\overline m=\overline{m'}$ and $\overline r=\overline{r'}$. It is enough to show $mr-m'r'\in IM$. However, this is clear since $mr-m'r'=m(r-r')+(m-m')r'$.